# Vertical View Pager either in Swift or in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, android-viewpager

Is it possible to implement Vertical ViewPager or not?

if Yes the please suggest me how to do it.
I am working on an app, which is similar to Quiz App.
I want to implement Quiz App result screen in which I am looking to implement Vertical View pager.

Thank you
Abhishek

Comment: A vertically paged scroll view?

Comment: Please refer video So You can easily get what I want to implement.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ekhbkudx4qjtpjk/AADGz4DPIeDLczbKtiL-1L1Ia?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that's simply a scroll view, or a subclass of (I.e. A table or collection view). The scroll direction is controlled by the content size (or the layout for the collection). Any scroll view can have paging enabled.

If using a table or collection you simply need to set the row height or item size to the size of the view. For a plain scroll view you add the page views as sub views and set their size to equal the scroll view frame.